# Why does the sum of two metrics give us a p-value above significance level but each metric viewed separately has p-value below significance level?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, ab-test

Suppose that we have an AB test in which the individuals have been evenly split. We are measuring many variables simultaneously for each one of the individuals of this test (for example, X and Y). All the variables only take values >= 0.

When doing a T-test on X values, we obtain a p-value = 0.02 and when doing T-test on Y values we obtain a p-value = 0.0001.

However, when taking the variable Z = X+Y (which has an important and relevant meaning in our particular experiment), the T-test gives us a p-value of 0.46.

Why is this happening? Obviously, the p-value is not linear but I'd like to know the precise meaning of these results.

Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Since you don't explain what X and Y are, it would be fair to consider the case $Y = -X.$  This results in a constant value of $0$ in *both* groups for $X+Y,$ reflecting no evidence of any difference--just as a p-value of $0.46$ is trying to tell you.

Comment: Thanks for your input! To clarify more, X and Y only can take values >= 0 so the case Y = -X only would be acceptable in the case both of them are 0.

Comment: Please give a little more consideration to the example, which is intended to be suggestive (and gives a strong hint concerning one possible explanation).  For instance, let $0\le X \le 1$ and set $Y = 1-X.$

Answer (score 2):

I think one thing people are missing is that variance adds in quadrature.  Without more information, it is impossible to say what the source of the problem is.  But it could be possible that the variance of Z is just sufficiently high to fail to reject the null.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, and as a commenter was suggesting, there is some negative correlation between $X$ and $Y$. Another possibility is that they are correlated differently with the A and B groups themselves -- e.g., $X$ is higher in group A, but $Y$ is higher in group B. When you add them together, you are then in a way "averaging out" these effects.

I'm aware this answer is not super precise, but hopefully it gives some intuition as to what could be happening. One way to look into this would be to plot your data -- what does the distribution of $X$ (and $Y$) look like? Are they correlated? What do the distributions look like within each A/B group? What do the correlations look like within each group?